# QTreeView with custom items

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm writing my first Qt application with PySide and am having some trouble creating a custom tree view. I'd like to list my own data in one column.
Each item must have text with tooltip, different text color, different background color, icons with actions and tooltip.

The default tree works.
I have view: `class TreeView(PySide.QtGui.QTreeView):`
and model: `class TreeModel(PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):`

How can I add different icons to my items?

Here is my example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# my test data
class MyData():
    def __init__(self, txt, parent=None):
        self.txt = txt
        self.parent = parent
        self.child = []
        self.icon = None
        self.index = None

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def position(self):
        position = 0
        if self.parent is not None:
            count = 0
            children = self.parent.child
            for child in children:
                if child == self:
                    position = count
                    break
                count += 1
        return position

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # test initialization
    @staticmethod
    def init():
        root = MyData("root")
        for i in range(0, 2):
            child1 = MyData("child %i" % (i), root)
            root.child.append(child1)
            for x in range(0, 2):
                child2 = MyData("child %i %i" % (i, x), child1)
                child1.child.append(child2)

        return root


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, tree):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__()
        self.__tree = tree
        self.__current = tree

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def flags(self, index):
        flag = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.isValid():
            flag |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return flag

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        node = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if parent.isValid():
            nodeS = parent.internalPointer()
            nodeX = nodeS.child[row]
            node = self.__createIndex(row, column, nodeX)
        else:
            node = self.__createIndex(row, column, self.__tree)
        return node

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def parent(self, index):
        node = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if index.isValid():
            nodeS = index.internalPointer()
            parent = nodeS.parent
            if parent is not None:
                node = self.__createIndex(parent.position(), 0, parent)
        return node

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        count = 1
        node = index.internalPointer()
        if node is not None:
            count = len(node.child)
        return count

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        data = None
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            node = index.internalPointer()
            data = node.txt

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            node = index.internalPointer()
            data = "ToolTip " + node.txt

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            data = QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")
        return data

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        result = True
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole and value != "":
            node = index.internalPointer()
            node.text = value
            result = True
        return result

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __createIndex(self, row, column, node):
        if node.index == None:
            index = self.createIndex(row, column, node)
            node.index = index
            icon = QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")
            b = self.setData(index, icon, QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
            b = self.setData(index, "ToolTip "+node.txt, QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole)
        return node.index



#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__model = model
        self.setModel(model)


        self.setCurrentIndex(self.__model.index(0, 0))
        return




#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyTree(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTree, self).__init__(parent)

        data = MyData.init()
        treeModel = TreeModel(data)
        treeView = TreeView(treeModel)

        self.setCentralWidget(treeView)


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyTree()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6):

I use my own QWidget

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# my test data
class Icon():
    def __init__(self, icon, tooltip):
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(icon)
        self.tooltip = tooltip

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# my test data
class MyData():
    def __init__(self, txt, parent=None):
        self.txt = txt
        self.tooltip = None
        self.parent = parent
        self.child = []
        self.icon = []
        self.index = None
        self.widget = None

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def position(self):
        position = 0
        if self.parent is not None:
            count = 0
            children = self.parent.child
            for child in children:
                if child == self:
                    position = count
                    break
                count += 1
        return position

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # test initialization
    @staticmethod
    def init():
        root = MyData("root")
        root.icon.append(Icon("icon.png", "ToolTip icon.png"))
        root.tooltip = "root tooltip"
        for i in range(0, 2):
            child1 = MyData("child %i" % (i), root)
            child1.icon.append(Icon("icon1.png", "ToolTip icon1.png"))
            child1.tooltip = "child1 tooltip"
            root.child.append(child1)
            for x in range(0, 2):
                child2 = MyData("child %i %i" % (i, x), child1)
                child2.icon.append(Icon("icon1.png", "ToolTip icon1.png"))
                child2.icon.append(Icon("icon2.png", "ToolTip icon2.png"))
                child2.tooltip = "child2 tooltip"
                child1.child.append(child2)

        return root

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TreeViewModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, tree):
        super(TreeViewModel, self).__init__()
        self.__tree = tree
        self.__current = tree
        self.__view = None

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def flags(self, index):
        flag = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.isValid():
            flag |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled \
                 | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return flag

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        node = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if parent.isValid():
            nodeS = parent.internalPointer()
            nodeX = nodeS.child[row]
            node = self.__createIndex(row, column, nodeX)
        else:
            node = self.__createIndex(row, column, self.__tree)
        return node

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def parent(self, index):
        node = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if index.isValid():
            nodeS = index.internalPointer()
            parent = nodeS.parent
            if parent is not None:
                node = self.__createIndex(parent.position(), 0, parent)
        return node

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        count = 1
        node = index.internalPointer()
        if node is not None:
            count = len(node.child)
        return count

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        data = None
        return data

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setView(self, view):
        self.__view = view

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __createIndex(self, row, column, node):
        if node.index == None:
            index = self.createIndex(row, column, node)
            node.index = index
        if node.widget is None:
            node.widget = Widget(node)
            self.__view.setIndexWidget(index, node.widget)
        return node.index


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setModel(model)
        model.setView(self)
        root = model.index(0, 0)
        self.setCurrentIndex(root)
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        k = event.key()
        if k == QtCore.Qt.Key_F2:
            self.__editMode()

        super(TreeView, self).keyPressEvent(event)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __editMode(self):
        index = self.currentIndex()
        node = index.internalPointer()
        node.widget.editMode(True, True)


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Label(QtGui.QLabel):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, text):
        super(Label, self).__init__(text)
        self.__parent = parent

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        #print("mouseDoubleClickEvent")
        if self.__parent is not None:
            self.__parent.editMode(True, True)
        else:
            super(Label, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, text):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(text)
        self.__parent = parent
        self.editingFinished.connect(self.__editingFinished)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        k = event.key()
        if k == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            print("ESC 2")
            self.__editingFinished(False)
        super(LineEdit, self).keyPressEvent(event)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __editingFinished(self, bCopy=True):
        print("editingFinished")
        self.__parent.editMode(False, bCopy)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, node):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.autoFillBackground()
        self.__node = node
        self.__bEditMode = False
        self.__txt = None
        self.__create(self.__node, self.__bEditMode)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __create(self, node, bEditMode):
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        for icon in node.icon:
            label = Label(None, node.txt)
            label.setPixmap(icon.pixmap)
            label.setToolTip("label tooltip %s %s" % (node.txt, icon.tooltip))
            layout.addWidget(label)

        self.__changeTxt(layout, node, bEditMode, False)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __changeTxt(self, layout, node, bEditMode, bCopy):
        if self.__txt is not None:
            if bCopy:
                node.txt = self.__txt.text()
            if isinstance(self.__txt, LineEdit):
                self.__txt.deselect()
            self.__txt.hide()
            layout.removeWidget(self.__txt)
            self.__txt = None

        if bEditMode:
            self.__txt = LineEdit(self, node.txt)
            self.__txt.setFrame(False)
            self.__txt.selectAll()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.__txt, QtCore.SLOT('setFocus()'));
        else:
            self.__txt = Label(self, node.txt)
        self.__txt.setToolTip("Text tooltip %s %s" % (node.txt, node.tooltip))
        layout.addWidget(self.__txt, 1)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def editMode(self, bEditMode, bCopy):
        if self.__bEditMode != bEditMode:
            self.__bEditMode = bEditMode
            layout = self.layout()
            self.__changeTxt(layout, self.__node, bEditMode, bCopy)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyTree(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTree, self).__init__(parent)

        data = MyData.init()
        frame = QtGui.QFrame();
        frame.setLayout( QtGui.QHBoxLayout() );

        treeViewModel = TreeViewModel(data)
        treeView = TreeView(treeViewModel)
        frame.layout().addWidget( treeView );

        self.setCentralWidget(frame)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyTree()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I opened one topic connected with this example. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420012/how-to-save-pyside-tree-view-model-structure