# PyQt: Saving native QTreeWidgets using QDataStream

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I recently spent some time working out how to use a QDataStream with a QTreeWidget in PyQt.  I never found specific examples for doing exactly this, and pyqt documentation for QDataStream seems to be pretty scarce in general.  So I thought I'd post a question here as a breadcrumb trail in case someone else down the line needs a hint.  I'll wait a bit in case someone would like to jump in and take a shot at it, and I'll post back in a bit with my own efforts.

The question is: In PyQt, how can I use a QDataStream to save QTreeWidgetItems to a file as native QT objects, and then read the file back to restore the tree structure exactly as it was saved?

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go ahead and show the method I used.  Hopefully I don't have an unfair advantage in knowing how I wanted my own problem solved :-)

If anyone has a cleaner or more pythonic take on this, please be welcome to follow up.  Thanks!

```
import sys,os.path
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class TreeExperiment(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

        self.tree=QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)                # 
        self.tree.setObjectName("treeWidget")            # 
        self.add_button=QtGui.QPushButton("Add", self)   # Initialize a simple
        self.save_button=QtGui.QPushButton("Save", self) # form containing a  
        gridlayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)             # treeWidget, an     
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.tree,1,0,1,9)          # 'Add' button, and a
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.add_button,2,0,2,3)    # 'Save' button
        gridlayout.addWidget(self.save_button,2,3,2,3)   #
        self.tree.headerItem().setText(0,"Label")        # 


        if os.path.isfile('native_tree_save.qfile'):
            # First look for a previously saved tree. If found, define
            # it as a QFile named 'file', open it, and define a datastream
            # to read from it.
            #
            # Each tree node is saved to and read from the file in pairs:
            # first, the QTreeWidgetItem itself, then the number of children
            # the item has so that the tree structure can be re-created
            # 
            # The first item is added directly as the root for simplicity,
            # and is sent to the function which begins the tree reconstruction

            file = QtCore.QFile('native_tree_save.qfile')
            file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)         
            datastream = QtCore.QDataStream(file)        
            child=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree.invisibleRootItem())
            child.read(datastream)
            num_childs=datastream.readUInt32()
            self.restore_item(datastream,child,num_childs)
        else: # Otherwise if this is the first use, create a root item
            new_item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
            self.tree.setCurrentItem(self.tree.topLevelItem(0))
            self.tree.currentItem().setText(0,'root')

        self.tree.setItemSelected(self.tree.topLevelItem(0),1)
        self.tree.setCurrentItem(self.tree.topLevelItem(0))

        self.connect(self.add_button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.add_item)
        self.connect(self.save_button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.save_tree)
        self.added_item_count=0

    def add_item(self): # Adds an item to whatever is selected
        self.added_item_count+=1
        label=str(self.added_item_count)
        new_item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree.currentItem())
        new_item.setText(0,label)
        self.tree.setCurrentItem(new_item)

    def restore_item(self,datastream,item,num_childs):
        for i in range(0, num_childs):
            child=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item)
            child.read(datastream)
            num_childs=datastream.readUInt32()
            self.restore_item(datastream,child,num_childs)

    def save_item(self,item,datastream):
        num_childs=item.childCount()
        for i in range(0,num_childs):
            child = item.child(i)
            child.write(datastream)
            num_childs=child.childCount()
            datastream.writeUInt32(num_childs)
            self.save_item(child,datastream)

    def save_tree(self):
        file = QtCore.QFile('native_tree_save.qfile')
        file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        datastream = QtCore.QDataStream(file)
        self.save_item(self.tree.invisibleRootItem(),datastream)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TreeExperiment()
    window.resize(200, 120)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

In [one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430792/984421) to a similar question, I wrote a simple demo that serializes to xml.

The same code can quite easily be adapted to work with QDataStream. I'm not really recommending this as a solution (there are probably dozens of different ways to achieve the same thing), but it does at least provide a working example:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)

from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, xml):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree.header().hide()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Export', self)
        self.button.clicked[()].connect(self.exportTree)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self._array = QtCore.QByteArray()
        self._buffer = QtCore.QBuffer(self._array, self)
        self._buffer.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        self._datastream = QtCore.QDataStream(self._buffer)
        self.importTree(xml)

    def importTree(self, xml):
        def build(item, root):
            for element in root.getchildren():
                child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item)
                data = element.attrib['data'].encode('ascii')
                self._array.swap(self._array.fromBase64(data))
                self._buffer.reset()
                self._datastream >> child
                build(child, element)
            item.setExpanded(True)
        root = etree.fromstring(xml)
        build(self.tree.invisibleRootItem(), root)

    def exportTree(self):
        def build(item, root):
            for row in range(item.childCount()):
                child = item.child(row)
                self._array.clear()
                self._buffer.reset()
                self._datastream << child
                data = self._array.toBase64().data().decode('ascii')
                element = etree.SubElement(root, 'node', data=data)
                build(child, element)
        root = etree.Element('root')
        build(self.tree.invisibleRootItem(), root)
        from xml.dom import minidom
        print(minidom.parseString(etree.tostring(root)).toprettyxml())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window("""\
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB/////wAA
                AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAYAUgBlAGQ=">
        <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAP//
                    //8AAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAgAQwB5AGEAbg==">
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAICA
                        AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAoARwByAGUAZQBu"/>
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAAAA
                        //8AAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAgAQgBsAHUAZQ=="/>
        </node>
        <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB/////6Wl
                    AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAwATwByAGEAbgBnAGU=">
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//+AgAAA
                        gIAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAwAUAB1AHIAcABsAGU="/>
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAICA
                        AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAoARwByAGUAZQBu"/>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAP//
                //8AAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAgAQwB5AGEAbg==">
        <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB/////6Wl
                    AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAwATwByAGEAbgBnAGU=">
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAP//
                        //8AAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAgAQwB5AGEAbg=="/>
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//+AgAAA
                        gIAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAwAUAB1AHIAcABsAGU="/>
        </node>
        <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAICA
                    AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAoARwByAGUAZQBu">
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB//8AAAAA
                        //8AAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAgAQgBsAHUAZQ=="/>
            <node data="AAAAAQAAAAEAAAAJAAAAQwAB/////wAA
                        AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAKAAAAAAYAUgBlAGQ="/>
        </node>
    </node>
</root>
        """)
    window.setGeometry(800, 300, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The QTreeWidget is a red herring. What you are saving is a generic QAbstractItemModel (`treeWidget->model()`) - after all, a `QTreeWidget` is a view, and has a built-in model. Now, those model's items are simply `QVariant`s, and those are simply Python types, but also fully supported by `QDataStream::operator<<`. All you need is to choose a tree traversal (depth-first, breadth-first, or something else), and dump the items and their depth in the tree to the stream. When you read the stream, that's sufficient information to reconstruct the tree.

Comment: Thanks-- I agree, that is a good description of the solution, hopefully I wasn't being deceptive in speaking about the treeWidget rather than its items.  It is exactly correct that the solution I arrived at depended on storing items and using them to populate the structure of a new treeWidget.

Would you like to offer a few lines of python code?  I see you are speaking in C++, but I wasn't able to make those operators work.  Using the QDataStream functionality was one of the tricks that took me a while to understand.

Comment: @EricMyers Will do tomorrow, I do use Python occasionally.