# Representing a Syntax Tree with QTreeview

Tags: qt, tree, pyqt, nlp, qtreeview

I'm studying on my master thesis and I'm to implement an application finding deep syntactic relations (in future we hope to use these to generate semantic relations) for Turkish texts.

I've prepared an interface with PyQt for our application and we need a visualization module representing a syntax tree for each sentence in our corpus, in a specified format.

A hand drown example syntax tree with morphological features for each word is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhj7D.png

Since already using Qt gui toolkit, I think, a quick way can be making use of Qtreeview for this purpose. But apperently, classic Qtreeview for filesystem needs some customizations.

Minimum expectations for tree items are:

1. a label for each connection to a node (if not possible, this can be added in node icons)
2. an icon for each intermediate node and root node
3. (an icon + a morphological features box) for each leave node

My question is how it can be implement such a representation with QTreeview. Especially for leave nodes, how can we generate a morphological features box?

If you have an idea guys, and give a small example, I'd be happy ^_^
Thanks for everyone read and think about this question...

Comment: Pyqtgraph have some custom widgets that might be of use? Run the examples application and have a look through everything.

Comment: @three_pineapples thank you man. I've just read the examples page of pyqtgraph's website. I've seen that there is some widgets related with trees : DataTreeWidget, TreeWidget and parametertree. I'll install pyqtgraph and run the examples of them. Soon inform about what I found.

Comment: There is also a FlowChart example that might be of use (though it looks like it is meant to represent the flow of data processing through functions which I don't think quite fits with what you want to do)

Comment: See also [QTreeView with custom items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278182/qtreeview-with-custom-items).

Comment: Thank you Trilarion for your suggestion. This is the practical solution to my answer. By inserting two icons in the beginning  (one for syntactic label and one for node type) of each item (which is a node) we can achieve a simple tree diagram appraoximate to what we want. Now I'm using qpainter and a recursive tree drawing algorithm that I've recently coded. If it fails, I try the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with QTreeView.

Look into QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView. These classes should be a very good solution for what you intend to do.

The [Diagram Scene Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As far as I understand from we must give the positions of our graphical elements(tree nodes) which will be connected. So must calculate them. I primarily look for a widget implemented for trees, that calculate all positions automatically according to graph data structure which our application will generate. And the diagram doesnt need to be interactive. Just a static one is adequate.

Comment: I don't think there is such a component. Maybe some third-party product I do not know. I suppose you will need to use the suggested classes even if they are more powerful than neccessary for you purpose.

Comment: Actually I used matplotlib and graphviz (an executable used via pygraphviz) for this. Graphviz was for layout calculations of nodes and the Matplotlib was for plotting the diagram. By this metod, I was able to generate a tree diagram which fullfils us visually. But the problem was its execution time. Graphviz is an external application and the matplotlib was too slow. So I decided to implement a tree diagram modul which uses Qt GUI toolkit for speed. Maybe I will calculate the layout by a custom algorithm and then  plot the diagram with Opainter or QGraphicsScene. Thanks for your advice man.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is what Trilarion suggest. The customization of the items of a qtreewidget.
link to related stackowerflow question and example is **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278182/qtreeview-with-custom-items)**